# ListDensityPlot: $n\times n$ matrix produces $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ result

Tags: plotting

When I use `ListDensityPlot`to plot a matrix with dimension $21\times400$, I find the result has dimension $20\times399$. 
When the dimension of the matrix is small, for example $5\times 5$, this problem still exists:

```
mat = Table[Tan[x + y], {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 5}];
ListDensityPlot[mat, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

This code produces an image of block matrix with dimension $4\times 4$.

I fail to find a similiar case, so I ask it here. Please help me.

Comment: Until behavior you have observed has been proven to be a bug, **please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result figure with four cells is right because the range of five point has four intervals. You can draw you `mat` by `ListPointPlot3D[mat]` and will see the five points:
[image]

Comment: If I want all the $5\times 5$ matrix elements to me plotted by ListDensityPlot, what should I do?

Comment: It is clear that you need 6x6 points to see the 5x5 cells using `ListDensityPlot`. However, you can build your figure using `Graphics[Flatten@Table[{Hue[0.03 x*y],Rectangle[{x,y}]},{x,1,5},{y,1,5}],Frame->True]`. The color specification instead `Hue[..]` could be any you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I think, this is near to what you want.

```
mat = Flatten[Table[{x, y, Tan[x + y]}, {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 5}], 1];
ListDensityPlot[mat, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but when dealing with large matrix, this way will cause some problem.